# Why there is an error when I use type hints in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

These codes are from leetcode.
I understand the type hints.
I can run it using leetcode without errors. But when I run it using jupyter or VS code, an error occurs.

```
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the beginning of your code:

```
from typing import List
```

This is the type hinting feature implemented in Python 3.5, see Python 3 documentation about [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in case you need to use more types in the future.